# Error while Transforming Classic SharePoint Pages To Modern - Index out of range

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, migration

I was trying to transform classic sharepoint home pages to modern home page for some sites using Powershell. I am getting the following error while trying to transform some home page sites.

> _Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.

I have tried to implement code from the below Microsoft page.
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/transform-classic-sharepoint-pages-to-modern-look-and-feel/

I have logged the error and got the below detail:

> *Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
>   Parameter name: index   at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException(ExceptionArgument argument, ExceptionResource resource)
>      at SharePointPnP.Modernization.Framework.Transform.ContentTransformator.LastColumnOrder(Int32 row, Int32 col)
>      at SharePointPnP.Modernization.Framework.Transform.ContentTransformator.Transform(List`1 webParts)
>      at SharePointPnP.Modernization.Framework.Transform.PageTransformator.Transform(PageTransformationInformation pageTransformationInformation)*

The home page only contains some list webparts.

The error is at the below command

```
    $modernPage = ConvertTo-PnPClientSidePage -Identity <pagename> -AddPageAcceptBanner -LogType File -LogFolder $logFolder -LogVerbose -Overwrite
```

Right now the result is that only few sites (home pages in site) get transformed and random site home pages are not transformed. I intend to transform all site home pages without any error

Comment: What does `$page.FieldValues["FileLeafRef"]` contain? The [-Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/convertto-pnpclientsidepage?view=sharepoint-ps) parameter takes just one page name, not an array of names.

Comment: Hi , It's the page name only...for some sites it's working..for some sites it's not..not sure it's because of this issue : https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-modernization/issues/320